# How do you update a value in a document in mongodb atlas?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, post, mongodb-atlas

I have a database with values like this:

[image]

I also have a post method with the goal of updating the startBudget when a form is submitted.

[image]

All I want to do is update the startBudget number in the database. I tried doing that by using the updateOne function but it didn't change anything in the database. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. It turns out I needed to use save instead of updateOne. All good.